# My python program don`t have access to files in mac

Tags: python, macos, permissions

I use this code to open files in my python script but I have problem the file are not acsesseble by the program.Only folders.Its mac system I have give full permission on .py file chmod 777 also to the txt files i need to use.Also I give permission to files for terminal and python.Still ca`t use the txt files when I open my y script from terminal.Also I move to from Desktop to Documents folder same result

```
def browseFiles_hstg(self):
filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",
                                  title = "Select a File",
                                  filetypes = (("Text files",
                                                "*.txt*"),
                                               ("all files",
                                                "*.*")))
```

Comment: Please add a full traceback of the exception that you are receiving upon code execution

Comment: I think is no traceback in the terminal

Comment: No output duo to can`t select the file